# Is there any way to replicate a memory can't be read error message in my C# application?

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql-server-2005, c#-2.0

Let me state upfront that I truly appreciate any assistance on this issue.

I have a C# (2.0) application. This is relatively simple application that executes stored procedures based on an XML file that is passed as a command line parameter.

We use it as a tool to call different stored procedures. This application does some logging and for the most part works very well.

The application reads the stored procedure name and parameters from an XML file. It sets up a connection string and SQL Command object (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand).

Then it runs the stored procedure with the ExecuteReader method.

Unfortunately on a handful of occasions this application has generated the following error:

```
    “Application popup: StoredProcLauncher.exe - Application Error : The instruction
 at "0x7c82c912" referenced memory at "0x00000000". The memory could not be "read”
```

This error has appeared on multiple servers so it must be a code issue.

It seems that when our production server rolls a certain number it belches out this memory error.

The problem is I don’t see this issue on development. I can’t replicate it so I’m stuck.

Is there any way to simulate this error. Can I fill up the memory on my local PC somehow to attempt to replicate this error?

Does anyone know some common coding issues that might result in an error like this?

Does anyone have some rope I can borrow?

Comment: For one, you can write the stack trace to the Windows Application event log (or text file, or email, etc) so the next time it happens on the server, you can view the stack trace and get some line numbers.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. Please post an answer so I can give you some StackOverflow Love.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to wrap the offending code in a try catch block and writing the stack trace and error message to the windows application event log, text file, email, etc.

This will give you some line numbers and additional information.

Also note, you may need to deploy this in debug mode or at least copy the .pdb file with the application exe/dll so it can get the debug symbols. Can't remember off the top of my head how that works, but I think when you deploy in release mode you may loose some valuable debug information.

Answer (score 2):

> The instruction at "0x7c82c912" referenced memory at "0x00000000"

This is an [access violation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx):

> An access violation occurs in unmanaged or unsafe code when the code attempts to read or write to memory that has not been allocated, or to which it does not have access. This usually occurs because a pointer has a bad value.

Why does your program have unmanaged/unsafe code? For doing what you described it needs no native code.

Alas, the code crashes and now is not the time to wonder how is ending up calling native code. To solve the issue you're going to have to catch a dump and analyze the dump. See [Capturing Application Crash Dumps](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx). There are tools that specialize in this, like [breakpad](https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/). there are also services that can help you collect and track crashes generated from your app, like [crittercism.com](https://www.crittercism.com/) or [AirBrake](https://airbrake.io/pages/home). I even created one for myself and made it public [bugcollect.com](http://bugcollect.com).